# Running GDB as a process with full user Interaction

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simple python program that invokes the gdb process and allows the user to have a bi-directional interaction with gdb. To start, I did something like this:

```
import subprocess
import sys

def runProcessNonBlocking(command, shell=False, cwd = None):

    if not shell:
        command = command.split()

    p = subprocess.Popen(command,
                        shell=shell,
                        cwd=cwd,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                        bufsize=1)

    while(True):
        # returns None while subprocess is running
        retcode = p.poll()
        line = p.stdout.readline()
        yield line
        if retcode is not None:
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":

    cmd = "gdb"

    try:
        for line in runProcessNonBlocking(cmd, shell=True):
            line_encoded = line.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
            print(line_encoded)

    except Exception as E:
        print("    Error: cannot run the command: %s" % E)
        sys.exit(2)
```

The code runs the GDB as a process and I can type commands and get output. However, the problem is that I cannot see what I am typing on the GDB prompt. What am I missing here?

Comment: STDOUT from your main process is connected to console. STDOUT from a subprocess is not attached to console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 1 problem with your code and one problem with how you run it.

```py
 while(True):
        # returns None while subprocess is running
        retcode = p.poll()
        line = p.stdout.readline()
        yield line
        if retcode is not None:
            break
```

In the above block you are yourself blocking the process output to come till it produces a line. This will cause nothing to be echoed till a new line character has come and hence make you feel that nothing being typed is being shown.

2nd issue is that by default python run itself in buffered mode. You need to disable that. Now there are multiple ways of doing that

```sh
$ PYTHONUNBUFFERED=true python3 test.py
```

or

```sh
$ python3 -u test.py
```

But this will make it dependent on how we are running it. So we even fix this in the code itself by making sure our print statements are flushed as soon as we use them

Below is the updated code

```py
import subprocess
import sys

def runProcessNonBlocking(command, shell=False, cwd = None):

    if not shell:
        command = command.split()

    p = subprocess.Popen(command,
                        bufsize=1,
                        shell=shell,
                        cwd=cwd,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT                        )

    while(True):
        # returns None while subprocess is running
        retcode = p.poll()
        line = p.stdout.read(1)
        yield line
        if retcode is not None:
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":

    import os
    cmd = ["gdb"]

    try:
        for line in runProcessNonBlocking(cmd, shell=True):
            line_encoded = line.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
            print(line_encoded, end='',flush=True)

    except Exception as E:
        print("    Error: cannot run the command: %s" % E)
        sys.exit(2)
```

[image: Working now]

Comment: Thanks @Tarun. I am using python logging. Does `print(line_encoded, end='',flush=True)` have an equivalent in logging like `log.info(line_encoded, flush=True)`

Comment: @ManiAm, sorry but I am not sure on that. I checked and couldn't find it